# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::groups() eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am creating a website using laravel. I have a small issue with eager loading. I have already made several websites with laravel, but still I can't find what is wrong here.

This is my config model:

```
<?php
class Config extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = "configs";

    public function groups() {
        return $this->hasMany('ConfigOptionGroup', 'config_id');
    }
}
```

And this is my testcontroller class:

```
<?php
namespace WebsiteController;
class DemoController extends \BaseController {

    public function getTest() {
        $c = \Config::where('id', 1)->with(['groups' => function($q){
            $q->whereNull('config_option_group_id');
        }])->first();

        return $c;
    }
}
```

Whenever I surf to the url that calls the `getTest` method I get an error saying `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::groups()`. However, the function `groups()` exists in the `Config` model.

When I remove the `with()` function from the query, it works just fine. But I can never load the groups via the relation.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

**Update:** I have removed the `Config` facade by commenting out the line in `/app/config/app.php`.

Comment: Have you tried this query renaming the relation?

Comment: Yes, I thought that maybe it was a keyword, but changing the relation name didn't work.

Comment: Does this work? `\Config::find(1)->groups()->get()`?

Comment: No, I still get the same error.

Comment: Pretty sure that if he namespaces the `Config` model, it would work just fine.

Comment: Strange. Can you quickly create a new model `Config2`, copy the whole class over and try again?

Comment: Somehow using `Config2` it works great. However, using seperate namespace I can't get it to work either.

Comment: Maybe running `composer dump-autoload` helps...

Comment: Thank you @lukasgeiter, this fixed my problem. Apparently I had two models with the name `Config`... -_-

Comment: Thought it was something like that...